# MacStore submission : app inside an app

Tags: mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox, osx-gatekeeper

How is it possible to submit and app to MacAppStore, which includes another app?

Should the other app have the same bundle identifier as the main app?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ever-changing third-party software distribution rules, not programming.

Comment: i dont belive its offtopic, its about codesigning and setting up your app - which you do in code

Comment: [Why customer support questions are off-topic here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Comment: you have it wrong Pascal, anyway, found the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Daemons and Services Programming Guide : "Applications can contain a helper application as a full application bundle, stored inside the main application bundle in the Contents/Library/LoginItems directory. Set either the LSUIElement or LSBackgroundOnly key in the Info.plist file of the helper application’s bundle."

Of course both applications must be sandboxed. The second application can't have the same bundle identifier than the main application because a bundle identifier must be unique on the device.

Comment: is there any reference to it? must it be Contents/Library/LoginItems ?